# Is there a rule of thumb to decide whether to use logic operators or not?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I came across an interview question:

We have numbers from 1 to n in any order. We start placing those numbers in any order into an array size n-1. This means that there will be one number that would not have been entered into the array. We have to find that.

Simple solution:

```
a = [4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7]
n = 7
print sum(range(1, n+1)) - sum(a) ## prints 6
```

One solution I found on the internet:

- XOR all elements from 1 ot n and store to X1
- XOR all elements of array and store to X2
- missing element = X1 XOR X2

The code that I made is:

```
print reduce(lambda a, b: a ^ b, range(1, n+1)) ^ reduce(lambda a, b: a ^ b, a) ## prints 6
```

In no way the second method was intuitive for me. Are there any specific use-cases where logical operators are applied this way?

Comment: It's correct, though it is a very odd way of doing it. Just for the sake of clarity: that's a bitwise operator, not a logical operator (that would work on the truthiness of the value).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: there's another way to solve this, using a well-known [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF):

```
n*(n+1)/2 - sum(a)
=> 6
```

And answering your question: no, this is *not* a good use case for abusing [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) between integers (not logical operators because the values are not booleans!) in such a way that it completely obscures the intent of the code. Stick with the arithmetical, intuitive solution. Use bitwise operators when the need arises to manipulate integers as binary values.

Comment: That is even better. But this `xor` solution is out of the box. Are those solutions result of hit and trials? I doubt if anybody would come up with this in an interview!!!

Comment: No, it's a well-known property of xor. It's used for RAID5 for instance (one disk stores the xored content of the other disks, which allows recovering the data if one of the disks breaks).

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operations especially XOR are important and can avoid overflows in this interview question. XOR is also the foundation of many crypto/checksum algorithms. [here](https://youtu.be/5OBZYhJnne0) is a good introduction video talking about bit operations (video link copied from [InterviewBit](https://www.interviewbit.com)).